# Is there a list of the number of required vocabulary for each TOPIK level?

Tags: vocabulary, topik

I wonder if there is any research on how many vocabulary is required for each TOPIK level. It should be something like the following:

> - TOPIK 1: 1000 words
> - TOPIK 2: 2500 words
> - TOPIK 3...
> - ...

And there should be an objective threshold on each level, such as the number of words to cover X% of the entire texts in the past Y years of TOPIK tests.

Is there any such research effort?

Comment: Few years ago they changed the topik format so the old topik 1-2 got merged into topik 1 and everything advanced got merged into topik 2, which should have changed the threshold of words to cover for each topik as well, so I don't think there is any such research effort

Comment: Moreover I have heard of plans to further change the topik format by 2022 so there might not be any such research effort in the near future either

Comment: They officially provide 2015 vocabulary lists for elementary and intermediate levels not that for each level. Visit [here](http://www.topik.go.kr/usr/cmm/subLocation.do?menuSeq=2110503&boardSeq=64217).

Answer (score 1):

TOPIK 1 is generally around 800 Words while TOPIK 2 is generally around 1500-2000 words, I'm not sure about the other levels though. I'd recommend using topikguide.com to study with a more official TOPIK vocab list. If you study TOPIK specific words you can probably get away with knowing less words.